# Error while laucnch a new ec2 instance by using chef workstation

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, redhat

```
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/lib/mixlib/cli.rb:230:in `parse_options': ambiguous option: --ssh (OptionParser::AmbiguousOption)
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.6.4/lib/chef/knife.rb:323:in `parse_options'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.6.4/lib/chef/knife.rb:303:in `initialize'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.6.4/lib/chef/knife.rb:217:in `new'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.6.4/lib/chef/knife.rb:217:in `run'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.6.4/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:156:in `run'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.6.4/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/bin/knife:255:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/knife:255:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you have a question? As the error says, you gave `--ssh` which is invalid.

Comment: Hi  All,It got resolved